# Which name is passed to Nginx when using CNAME

Tags: nginx, dns, cname

I have a Nginx server on my own server. I have a DDNS from asuscomm.com e.g. mydomain.asuscomm.com. Now I want to be able to handle to different sites using CNAME and Nginx.

www.domain1.com and www.domain2.com. In my DNS I want both to point to mydomain.asuscomm.com, and then depending on if it is www.domain1.com or www.domain2.com I want to show different sites.

Is it possible to do with CNAME and Nginx, or do I have to have an A pointer for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The name you see in browser's address bar.

Comment: @AndreasSelenwall did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

CNAME is pointer to domain, and A is pointer to IP, you need to define A for IP (Nginx port 80).

You can try [subdomain for nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/set-up-a-sub-domain-on-a-nginx-server-ubuntu-12-04)